# Cancel/stop WebView navigation

Tags: c#, windows-8

How to stop the navigation when  navigate(url) is downloading the html content on the webview? I have tried this

```
 private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     WebView1.LoadCompleted -= new Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(load_Completed);               
 }

 private void load_Completed(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     //some code after the content is loaded  
 }
```

but the navigation process does not stop...

Comment: Do you mean ASP.Net? There are lots of differnt webframe available in c#. Specifying this in your title would help be help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of WebView do you use, but probably you can do somthing like that:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         string[] args = { "history.go(-1);" };
         WebView1.InvokeScript("eval", args);
     }
     catch {}
 }
```

Comment: @david waters..yes I guess...I am kind of new to app development...so I am making an app using c# and xaml on visual studio express ..

Comment: ...intellisense is showing an error with the argument of invokescript...

Comment: What kind of error? Should I guess?

Comment: error says invokescript has invalid arguments 
argument 2: cannot convert string to string[]

Comment: So InvokeScript extects to get an array of strings, but not a string. So, pack call into array. (My answer was fixed). BTW are you working on W8 Store application?

Comment: I tried making a cancel button 

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                    
            WebView1.Unloaded += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(cancel_load);
                   }

private void cancel_load(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }


intellisense says Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventHandler' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler'

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx  Unloaded that is not what you need. Did you try my updated answer?

Comment: sorry i'm not very clear with packing a call into array. (its my first app :( )...and yes I am making a W8 store app

Comment: Thats why I updated my answer. Just copy the code.

Comment: Anyone knows how to solve this in Windows 10 C# UWP?